# Flexbox - justify-content center item arrangement

Tags: css, flexbox

The issue I am having right now is that `justify-content:center` will not align the item from left if the items are less than the width of the container.

Below is the output that I get and expect:
[image]

Top is what I get now, here is the link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myzgaexu/3/).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:60%;
  justify-content:center;
}
.flex-item-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.flex-item-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
</div>
```

Bottom is what I want the output to be like.

Comment: You can try grid instead of flex if you don't want the white space on sides.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can achieve the second image by setting

```
flex-wrap: wrap; 
justify-content: flex-start;
```

*EDIT*

check out the link to the new answer
https://jsfiddle.net/tcqpxf24/3/

What I did is add a second div to act as a parent for the flex children then styled it so that it's justified to the start to center it in the middle of the top div. I added `justify-content: center;` to the top div.
It looks like that now!
[image]

Comment: is that what you're after? if not please let me know!

Comment: This will remove the white space at the left and right of the container.

Comment: you can add it back with `margin: 0 auto;` at the parent component

Comment: @MahmoudMuhammed but there will be white space on the right (depends on the size of the screen). I don't mind having white space on both side, as long as they are even

Comment: I'll edit the answer

Comment: @StacieT.  check it out now and let me know if that solves your problem

Comment: yes! this is exactly what I want. thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! :D

Comment: @StacieT. please check the result very well, the spaces on each side aren't the same here

Comment: Getting this specific example looking pixel perfect was never the goal. it's more of the idea of how to achieve something like this. `justify-content: center;` will always keep spaces on right and left equal to one another.

Comment: the exact reason why that is happening though is `flex-wrap as there is no place for the last elements in the row to render, it breaks on to the next line leaving the white space behind. That's why the space on the right is larger than the left.
https://jsfiddle.net/o7g8fvkj/1/ check this to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `grid` if you don't want side spaces on different window sizes:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(3rem, 1fr));
}

.flex-item-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-blue">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-grey">2</div>
</div>
```

If you want the side space you can simply apply something like `padding: 0 10px;` to the main container.